# Elliptic Curve Point Division

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups, elliptic-curves

I have seen several different responses to this type of question, and I find them all contradictory or unclear.  This is a multi-part question.

1. If I have a point Q on an elliptic curve over a finite field, can it be divided by an integer say 2 to find the point which generates it by being doubled?

To illustrate, let's take a toy example that I have seen elsewhere:
$y^2 = x^3 + ax + b$

where:

a = -2

b = 1

*modulus = 89

With a Generator Point of (4,18)
We get the set:

```
1 * P = (4, 18)    2 * P = (45, 73)
3 * P = (49, 28)   4 * P = (80, 64)
5 * P = (27, 36)   6 * P = (11, 81)
7 * P = (66, 47)   8 * P = (58, 40)
9 * P = (76, 12)   10 * P = (43, 52)
11 * P = (53, 26)  12 * P = (0, 88)
13 * P = (13, 6)   14 * P = (54, 19)
15 * P = (20, 60)  16 * P = (26, 80)
17 * P = (64, 88)  18 * P = (10, 64)
19 * P = (25, 88)  20 * P = (81, 22)
21 * P = (14, 15)  22 * P = (88, 25)
23 * P = (31, 2)   24 * P = (1, 0)
25 * P = (31, 87)  26 * P = (88, 64)
27 * P = (14, 74)  28 * P = (81, 67)
29 * P = (25, 1)   30 * P = (10, 25)
31 * P = (64, 1)   32 * P = (26, 9)
33 * P = (20, 29)  34 * P = (54, 70)
35 * P = (13, 83)  36 * P = (0, 1)
```

So, for example, I know that doubling 7*P (66,47) gives me the point 14*P (54,19).

2. Is there a division operation which can take the point (54,19) and give me (66,47)?  If so, could I do it again to 7*P, and what would be the result? 3*P or 4*P?

In [this blog post](http://andrea.corbellini.name/2015/05/23/elliptic-curve-cryptography-finite-fields-and-discrete-logarithms/) towards the top, she mentions the Multiplicative Inverse being used in the division operation.

I am using a C# Library ([found here](https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/vstudio/Elliptic-Curve-Arithmetic-2c433b84/sourcecode?fileId=145524&pathId=1748921262)) to calculate the values above, and it also has an "Extended Euclidean" Function which when I plug in 14*P (54,19) spits out (6,-17).

3. Is (6,-17) the multiplicative inverse of (54,19), and if so how do I use it to get back to (66,47)
4. If this is possible, can the same rules be applied to very large sets for example NIST P-192 or the secp256k1?

Thanks for your consideration and time.

Comment: What is the modulus for this curve?

Comment: Not every point can be divided by any integer. If $n\in\mathbb N$ and $E$ is an elliptic curve over a finite field $\mathbb F_q$, then you can divide all $\mathbb F_q$-rational point of $E$ by $n$ if and only if $\gcd(n,|E(\mathbb F_q)|)=1$. Just like in any finite abelian group.

Comment: I can't believe that I left that out.  I'm editing the question now.

Comment: @Ferra so, I am assuming that only the points from my example which are even numbers * P are divisible by 2.  _How do I then go about the division?_

Comment: I would say that you write down the generic equations for doubling a point, you equal them to the point that you have and you solve. Alternatively, but I guess it boils down to the same calculations, say that you have $Q$ and you want to divide it by 2. Take the pencil of lines passing through $-Q$, and intersect it with $E$. You will get a parametric equation of degree 3, say with parameter $t$. The discriminant is a polynomial of degree 3 in $t$. Its roots are the slopes of the lines which pass through $Q$ and $Q/2$, if there are any.

Comment: @ThereIsNoSky I came across this question because I'm in exact same situation. Pulling down the c# example I wasn't able to generate the same set of numbers as you using the `a=-2`. `b=1`, `p=89`. My results start with `1 * P = (3, 45)`. Are you sure those numbers are right? I tried every prime number < 100 for p with no luck.

Comment: @Levitikon - You have to set your first point to (4,18), and then you add it to itself to get the rest of the set.  EX:
'code'
 BigInteger a = -2;
 BigInteger b = 1;
 BigInteger p = 89;
 BigInteger x = 4;
 BigInteger y = 18;
 BigInteger k = 1;
 EllipticCurve ec = new EllipticCurve(0, 0, 0, a, b, p, p);
 ECPoint P = new ECPoint(p, p, x, y);
 ECPoint P2 = null;
'code'

Comment: OK, apparently, I'm too slow and accidentally hit enter instead of shift+enter.  Sorry.  Here is the full example:
'code'
 BigInteger a = -2;
 BigInteger b = 1;
 BigInteger p = 89;
 BigInteger x = 4;
 BigInteger y = 18;
 BigInteger k = 1;
 EllipticCurve ec = new EllipticCurve(0, 0, 0, a, b, p, p);
 ECPoint P = new ECPoint(p, p, x, y);
 ECPoint P2 = null;
 ECPoint P3 = null;
 ECPoint P4 = null;
 P2 = ec.Addition(P, P);
 P3 = ec.Addition(P, P2);
 P4 = ec.Addition(P, P3);
'code'
I haven't tested that code, so let me know if you have problems with it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After doing some additional research on this topic, I think I have found an answer to my question.  I do appreciate everyone's comments, and the first answer provided, as they helped move me towards where I wanted to go with this.

1. Yes and no.  On several levels.  In order to divide on the elliptic curve you must find the multiplicative inverse of the SCALAR by which you want to divide.  In the question I suggest dividing by 2.  In order to do this you must find the multiplicative inverse of the scalar 2 on the specific curve / set / Field you are working with.  (I know that there are differences between those, but I won't get into the nuances as I'm not an expert)
   It's important to realize that division is just multiplication by the "multiplicative inverse".  I believe that it is only possible to multiply a point in a set like this by a Scalar, so therefore you can only divide by a scalar, and the multiplicative inverse is therefore a scalar.

   - Now for the "NO".  Not all Fields have a multiplicative inverse for all numbers, and not all numbers when multiplied by a multiplicative inverse yield a point on the curve.
2. In short, yes.  But I'm trying to go about it in the wrong way.  The Extended Euclidean Algorithm takes 2 arguments.  The number for which you are trying to find the multiplicative inverse (2) and the modulus of the Field (89).  It then returns 3 values- x, y, gcd.  The multiplicative inverse is x % p.  (a SCALAR).  I determined this by additional analysis of [the blog post](http://andrea.corbellini.name/2015/05/23/elliptic-curve-cryptography-finite-fields-and-discrete-logarithms/) I mentioned in the question.  Follow the python script closely.

   - 14*P when multiplied by the multiplicative inverse of 2 will yield the point 7*P.
   - 7*P when multiplied by the multiplicative inverse of 2 will yield a point I like to think of as 3.5*P.  This point won't necessarily be in the set or even on the curve.  This is because 7 is not evenly divisible by 2 and the set only contains Integers*P.
3. No, the multiplicative inverse is a SCALAR, not a point.
4. Yes, I believe these rules are applicable to all EC sets.

If I have made any grossly inaccurate statements in this answer, please point them out, and I will most likely update my answer.

Comment: What do you mean by "3.5\ast P"?

Comment: @LordSharktheUnknown Well, it's not 3*P and it's not 4*P.  And, if you add (1*P)/2 to the result, you get 4*P.  So I think of it like 3.5*P.  I know it's not necessarily traditional, but it's just how I look at it.

Comment: @ThereIsNoSky Out of curiosity, have you discovered any other way of detecting if the nP being divided by 2 is odd, other than the point produced not being on the curve? Because I'm not sure that's always true. Using the SECP256k1 curve, I'm seeing that 3*P / 2 is producing a point on the curve `(89636686429439908262420422079980100111093242688153882571369946125714247242771, 10834049905482024808827094233028503931704324296739647619935835709590451240976)`

Comment: Even 0.5*P is on the curve. It seems like there ought to be some sort of sign we're looking at a fractional point. Although, it's pretty mind bending to think about these actually being on the curve. Where can they possibly be? It's like the Upside Down Place in Stranger Things.

Comment: As a further note to this, I think that if you can find the multiplicative inverse for a Finite Field then the points are always on the curve / in the field.  This is because you are simply multiplying your point by a SCALAR, and any point in the field multiplied by a Scalar generates a point on the curve and in the field.  (Why all n*P are in the field and on the curve).  I'm stretching here, so if someone sees an error in my ways, please correct me.

Comment: I think this is incorrect. There is nothing you can multiply the point $14P$ by in order to get the point $7P$, because the order of the point $14P$ is 24, and $\gcd(14,24) \neq 1$, so you can't solve the equation $14x \equiv 7 \pmod{24}$. $14P$ multiplied by the multiplicative inverse of 2 mod 89, yields the point $6P$. However 14 the scalar multiplied by the inverse of 2 mod 89 will give you 7.

Answer (score 1):

If you could divide 7P by 2 the result would be 48P because doubling 48P gives 7P:

48 * 2 mod 89 = 96 mod 89 = 89 + 7 mod 89 = 7

(I'm guessing you're trying to divide nP by 2 until you get to 1P. That won't help you any more than doing P + P + P... to get to nP. Unless n is a power of 2)

Comment: This is incorrect (see my comment above). $48P$ is the point at infinity, because the order of $P$ is 48, so doubling it will just give you the point of infinity again, not $7P$